# jQuery Lightbox - image duplication

Tags: jquery

I've created a gallery of images and wanted to create a jQuery lightbox for the images. After having some issues attempting to learn the language and create my own, I decided to use the one from... http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

The problem I'm having now is when I include it into my image gallery, it duplicates the image. By that I mean, when the image in the gallery is clicked the lightbox pops up with the image, but it also has one of the "next" arrows on the side of the image which when it is clicked it takes you to a copy of the same image. It also includes the option to include a caption on the image, and only one of the two (same images) has the caption. Does anyone know how to solve this? I only want one image.

I included one of the lines of code which I am adding the lightbox information to (data-lightbox="image-1" title="My caption"). I added it right after the first optimized image.

```
<li class="gallery_item"><a class="no_decor" href="../images/galleryimages/Optimized-SAM_4910.JPG"><p><img class="border" src="../images/galleryimages/Optimized-SAM_4910.JPG" width="200px" height="200px">Name</a><br/>price</p></li>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Move the

```
  <p>
```

tag outside the

```
  <a>
```

tag and you might solve your problem.  That kind of thing can be an odd issue.

```
<li class="gallery_item"><p><a class="no_decor" href="../images/galleryimages/Optimized-SAM_4910.JPG"><img class="border" src="../images/galleryimages/Optimized-SAM_4910.JPG" width="200px" height="200px">Name</a><br/>price</p></li>
```

Comment: Thanks. I reformatted some of my other classes so I could removed the <p> tag, and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing data-lightbox attribute in you code and remove the `<p>` tag. `<p>` tag is incorectly added.

```
<li class="gallery_item"><a data-lightbox="example-1" class="no_decor" href="../images/galleryimages/Optimized-SAM_4910.JPG"><p><img class="border" src="../images/galleryimages/Optimized-SAM_4910.JPG" width="200px" height="200px"></p>Name</a><br/>price</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar issue with a series of Lightbox images. Mine was displaying 'Image 5 of 6' when there were only 5 images in the series and when you viewed the sixth image it was just a duplicate of the fifth image. This was due to my code not having the closing `</a>` tag for the 5th image's hyperlink. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of my image gallery starting at 4/30 instead of 1/15 and it duplicated the images. I changed the lightbox.js parameters for the infinite loop and seemed to resolve the problem.

$('.yourclass').slick({
  dots: false,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3,
  responsive: []